# Need to Search between words in elastic search Please advice how can I handle

Tags: java, elasticsearch, search

Hi I am looking for search function where we need to search between words in elastic search . Ryt now our search work like if we want search for “company name” we need to search with “c” , “n”,”co”,”comp”,”na”,”nam” but req is if we search with “mp”, “any”,”ame “, “me”, “p” result should give “company name”. Please advice how can we handle this is there any such type of search functionality, I tried wild card but it is not working for multiple fields please advise if I miss anything or suggest me how to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use [N-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) that first breaks text down into
> words whenever it encounters one of a list of specified characters,
> then it emits N-grams of each word of the specified length.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and results.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 50
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "body": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Analyze API**

```
GET/_analzye
{
  "analyzer" : "my_analyzer",
  "text" : "company name"
}
```

Following tokens are generated

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "c",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 1,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "co",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "com",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "comp",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "compa",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "compan",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 5
    },
    {
      "token": "company",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 6
    },
    {
      "token": "o",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 7
    },
    {
      "token": "om",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 8
    },
    {
      "token": "omp",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 9
    },
    {
      "token": "ompa",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 10
    },
    {
      "token": "ompan",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 11
    },
    {
      "token": "ompany",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 12
    },
    {
      "token": "m",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 13
    },
    {
      "token": "mp",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 14
    },
    {
      "token": "mpa",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 15
    },
    {
      "token": "mpan",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 16
    },
    {
      "token": "mpany",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 17
    },
    {
      "token": "p",
      "start_offset": 3,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 18
    },
    {
      "token": "pa",
      "start_offset": 3,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 19
    },
    {
      "token": "pan",
      "start_offset": 3,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 20
    },
    {
      "token": "pany",
      "start_offset": 3,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 21
    },
    {
      "token": "a",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 22
    },
    {
      "token": "an",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 23
    },
    {
      "token": "any",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 24
    },
    {
      "token": "n",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 25
    },
    {
      "token": "ny",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 26
    },
    {
      "token": "y",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 27
    },
    {
      "token": "n",
      "start_offset": 8,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 28
    },
    {
      "token": "na",
      "start_offset": 8,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 29
    },
    {
      "token": "nam",
      "start_offset": 8,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 30
    },
    {
      "token": "name",
      "start_offset": 8,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 31
    },
    {
      "token": "a",
      "start_offset": 9,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 32
    },
    {
      "token": "am",
      "start_offset": 9,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 33
    },
    {
      "token": "ame",
      "start_offset": 9,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 34
    },
    {
      "token": "m",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 35
    },
    {
      "token": "me",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 36
    },
    {
      "token": "e",
      "start_offset": 11,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 37
    }
  ]
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "body": "company name"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "body": "ame"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64975316",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.941854,
        "_source": {
          "body": "company name"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @harish kumar did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: Yes It is working but can we use this if we have filters, and one more query

Comment: In highlighting search for my application how search works for us is if we pass pageSize it will only return one matching field from record. 
For example 
There are 4 records

Comment: [
   {
      "name":”jhon",
      "Age":24,
      "lastname":"willam",
      "firstname":"henry"
   },
   {
      "name":”kellin",
      "Age":24,
      "lastname":"kevin",
      "firstname":"mathew"
   },
   {
      "name":”keeper",
      "Age":24,
      "lastname":"Jr",
      "firstname":"gomez"
   },
   {
      "name":”Asif",
      "Age":24,
      "lastname":"peter",
      "firstname":"willaim kemp"
   }
]

Comment: user searching with "ke"

result will be like 
{
   "results": [
      {
         "fieldId": "name",
         "matchingText": "Kellin"
      },
      {
         "fieldId": "name",
         "matchingText": "keeper"
      },
      {
         "fieldId": "name",
         "matchingText": "willaim kemp"
      }
   ],
   "total_count": 4, //total number of records matching in es index
   "page": 1, 
   "pageSize": 3  //total no records per page
}

Comment: As u observed it is returning the only one matching fields per record it is ignoring if other fields matching also it is returning one per record. so what I understood is that it is returning one matching attribute for per record, it is ignoring other fields, this is happening only for highlight search regular search is fine how can I implement to get result of all matching fields like one record 5 matching fields it should return all 5 and then after next record matching fields.

Comment: how can we get total count should be total number of matching fields through out index and page size to be total number of matching fields for page

Comment: your answer will be helpful

Comment: @harishkumar thank u for updating here, I will go through your other question as well.

Comment: @harishkumar thank u for accepting my answer, can you please upvote the answer as well :)